# consuming a weird appended response in a WSDL with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I'm using this webservice through php

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx?wsdl';
$soap = new soapClient($wsdl);
try{
$return = $soap->GetCountriesByContinent(array('continentCode'=>'AS'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
var_dump($return->GetCountriesByContinentResult);
```

I'm getting  this result:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["schema"]=> string(607) "" ["any"]=> string(6747) "AFAFGAfghanistanAMARMArmeniaAZAZEAzerbaijanBHBHRBahrainBDBGDBangladeshBTBTNBhutanIOIOTBritish Indian Ocean TerritoryBNBRNBruneiKHKHMCambodiaCNCHNChinaCXCXRChristmas IslandCCCCKCocos IslandsGEGEOGeorgiaHKHKGHong KongININDIndiaIDIDNIndonesiaIRIRNIranIQIRQIraqILISRIsraelJPJPNJapanJOJORJordanKZKAZKazakhstanKWKWTKuwaitKGKGZKyrgyzstanLALAOLaosLBLBNLebanonMOMACMacaoMYMYSMalaysiaMVMDVMaldivesMNMNGMongoliaMMMMRMyanmarNPNPLNepalKPPRKNorth KoreaOMOMNOmanPKPAKPakistanPSPSEPalestinian TerritoryPHPHLPhilippinesQAQATQatarSASAUSaudi ArabiaSGSGPSingaporeKRKORSouth KoreaLKLKASri LankaSYSYRSyriaTWTWNTaiwanTJTJKTajikistanTHTHAThailandTRTURTurkeyTMTKMTurkmenistanAEAREUnited Arab EmiratesUZUZBUzbekistanVNVNMVietnamYEYEMYemen" }
```

As you can see, getting an array on this way is useless because everything is appended.
So, which is the right way to consume this service?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSDL definition determines how the SoapClient forms requests and interprets responses.

The method you are trying to access has a response defined as so:

```
<s:element name="GetCountriesByContinentResponse">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCountriesByContinentResult">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element ref="s:schema" />
            <s:any />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

So PHP is converting the XML response to `schema` and `any`. `any` is just a string version of the XML contents.

The contents of `any` should be valid XML, so if you can't modify the WDSL you can always read the string with an XML parser.

Comment: You are a genius dude, just a little googling from your idea and got this: $a = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($return->GetCountriesByContinentResult->any)),1); Now everything goes perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its as very simple XML output you can try something like this

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx?wsdl';
$soap = new soapClient($wsdl);
try {
    $return = $soap->GetCountriesByContinent(array('continentCode' => 'AS'));
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($return->GetCountriesByContinentResult->any);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "ISO2\tISO3\tCountry Name\n";
    foreach ( $xml->NewDataSet->Countries as $country ) {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", $country->ISO2, $country->ISO3, $country->Country);
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Output

```
ISO2    ISO3    Country Name
AF  AFG Afghanistan
AM  ARM Armenia
AZ  AZE Azerbaijan
BH  BHR Bahrain
BD  BGD Bangladesh
BT  BTN Bhutan
IO  IOT British Indian Ocean Territory
BN  BRN Brunei
KH  KHM Cambodia
CN  CHN China
CX  CXR Christmas Island
CC  CCK Cocos Islands
GE  GEO Georgia
HK  HKG Hong Kong
IN  IND India
ID  IDN Indonesia
IR  IRN Iran
IQ  IRQ Iraq
IL  ISR Israel
JP  JPN Japan
JO  JOR Jordan
KZ  KAZ Kazakhstan
KW  KWT Kuwait
KG  KGZ Kyrgyzstan
LA  LAO Laos
LB  LBN Lebanon
MO  MAC Macao
MY  MYS Malaysia
MV  MDV Maldives
MN  MNG Mongolia
MM  MMR Myanmar
NP  NPL Nepal
KP  PRK North Korea
OM  OMN Oman
PK  PAK Pakistan
PS  PSE Palestinian Territory
PH  PHL Philippines
QA  QAT Qatar
SA  SAU Saudi Arabia
SG  SGP Singapore
KR  KOR South Korea
LK  LKA Sri Lanka
SY  SYR Syria
TW  TWN Taiwan
TJ  TJK Tajikistan
TH  THA Thailand
TR  TUR Turkey
TM  TKM Turkmenistan
AE  ARE United Arab Emirates
UZ  UZB Uzbekistan
VN  VNM Vietnam
YE  YEM Yemen
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the wsdl is valid, I would try to download the wsdl manually and save it as a local file and access it that way.  I have found the soapClient in php to not be very good at consuming urls for wsdl's especially ones that have get parameter strings.  If this works for you, great. As soap is a dying religion, i wouldn't expect this fixed anytime soon.

You could use the old nusoap library if you must leave the wsdl remote--although i have never seen anyone really build a responsive service to automatically update on wsdl change in my entire career...

Comment: nusoap didn't do the trick, it turned out to be an XML description, just have to parse it. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Check your source code, that long text you think is appended has some XML tags that aren't showing up (your browser doesn't know how to interpret "<Country>". Maybe they expect you to parse it further before using?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, needed to parse the response. this did the trick: $a = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($return->GetCountriesByContinentResult->any)),1);